# Using chui.js $.UIDeletable when there are two lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chui.js

I'm using chui.js (http://chocolatechip-ui.com) framework for this code

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/fjKx3/2/

It's supposed to be 2 screens: the left one can slide out using `$.UISlideout()`. I want to have "Edit" button for left screen **only** but it seems that `$.UIDeletable` applied to both lists in both screens.

**HTML**:

```
<nav>
  <h1>Page Name</h1>
</nav>
<article>
  <section>
    <ul class='list'>
      <li class='comp'>
        <aside>
          <img width="48px" src='http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/files/2009/09/twitter_new_default_avatar.png' />
        </aside>
        <div>
          <h3>Item 1</h3>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum mass</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class='comp'>
        <aside>
          <img width="48px" src='http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/files/2009/09/twitter_new_default_avatar.png' />
        </aside>
        <div>
          <h3>Item 2</h3>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum mass</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class='comp'>
        <aside>
          <img width="48px" src='http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/files/2009/09/twitter_new_default_avatar.png' />
        </aside>
        <div>
          <h3>Item 3</h3>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum mass</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class='comp'>
        <aside>
          <img width="48px" src='http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/files/2009/09/twitter_new_default_avatar.png' />
        </aside>
        <div>
          <h3>Kiss</h3>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum mass</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class='comp'>
        <aside>
          <img width="48px" src='http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/files/2009/09/twitter_new_default_avatar.png' />
        </aside>
        <div>
          <h3>Item 4</h3>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum mass</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</article>
<div class='hidden' id='list-temp'>
  <h2>
    Your List
  </h2>
  <ul class='list' id='my-list'>
    <li>
      <h3>Item A</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item B</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item C</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item D</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $.UISlideout();
    $('.slide-out > section').append($('#list-temp').html());

    $.UIDeletable({
        list: '.list', 
        callback: function(item) {
            var text = $(item).siblings('h3').text();
            console.log(text);
        }
    });

});
```

I have tried to change the left list to some #id and select that. Still don't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to drop `chocolatechip-ui` since this is either so brand new or abandon, there is no answer from anyone including the founder.

Square UI easily solved that problem:

https://github.com/ququplay/jquery-mobile-square-ui-theme